# Parsing The json decoded array in php

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($jsonobj); //this shows me the op as:


Array ( 
[0] => 
    stdClass Object ( 
        [businessId] => 6 
        [subscriptionId] => 6 
        [name] => Eazy Borehole Drillers Limited 
        [city] => Blantyre 
        [pin] => 3332 
        [region] => Southern Region 
        [area] => City Centre 
        [address] => P.O. Box 3332 Blantyre 
        [email] => eazybhd@yahoo.com 
        [website] => eazyboreholedrillers.com 
        [district] => Blantyre 
        [phonenumber] => 265999434445 
        [category] => 14 
) 
[1] => 
    stdClass Object ( 
        [businessId] => 7 
        [subscriptionId] => 7 
        [name] => Eazy Travel Limited 
        [city] => Blantyre 
        [pin] => 3332 
        [region] => Southern Region 
        [area] => City Centre 
        [address] => P.O. BOX 3332 Blantyre 
        [email] => eazytravell@yahoo.com 
        [website] => eazytravell.com 
        [district] => Blantyre 
        [phonenumber] => 265999434445 
        [category] => 15 
) 
[2] =>
    stdClass Object ( 
        [businessId] => 20 
        [subscriptionId] => 20 
        [name] => Malswitch 
        [city] => Blantyre 
        [pin] => 384 
        [region] => Southern Region
        [area] => City Centre 
        [address] => PO Box 384 
        [email] => info@malswitch.com 
        [website] => www.malswitch.com 
        [district] => Blantyre 
        [phonenumber] => 01 820 414 
        [category] => 69 
) 
[3] =>
    stdClass Object ( 
        [businessId] => 21 
        [subscriptionId] => 21 
        [name] => Malawi Savings Bank 
        [city] => Blantyre 
        [pin] => 521 
        [region] => Southern Region 
        [area] => Cicty Centre 
        [address] => PO Box 521 PO Box 521 
        [email] => balaka@msb.mw 
        [website] => www.msb.mw 
        [district] => Blantyre 
        [phonenumber] => 01 831 016 / 01 
        [category] => 69 
)
```

Now my question is how to take the inside values like `[businessId]`,`[subscriptionId]` out of this so that i can use them in my html page.

Comment: a simple foreach should suffice: `foreach($jsonobj as $key => $value)   { echo $value->businessId; }` etc.. something like that

Comment: you can try get_object_vars() http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: @kevinabelita Thanks a lot... how easy it was... i was doing as echo $value[businessId].... :-))

Comment: @SohamsMore since `$jsonobj` contains objects inside, each copy of `$value` inside the foreach is an object. to access its values you need to use the `->` (arrow notation) to get them. your welcome.

Answer (score 1):

you use this 'array->key'. example array->businessId;

```
$data = Array ( 
[0] => 
    stdClass Object ( 
        [businessId] => 6 
        [subscriptionId] => 6 
        [name] => Eazy Borehole Drillers Limited 
        [city] => Blantyre 
        [pin] => 3332 
        [region] => Southern Region 
        [area] => City Centre 
        [address] => P.O. Box 3332 Blantyre 
        [email] => eazybhd@yahoo.com 
        [website] => eazyboreholedrillers.com 
        [district] => Blantyre 
        [phonenumber] => 265999434445 
        [category] => 14 
)
)

$data[0]->businessId;
$data[0]->subscriptionId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON object contains objects itself, which you can access with `->`. Try this:

```
$jsonobj = ...; // Fetch your JSON object

foreach($jsonobj as $item) {
    echo $item->businessId;     // 6
    echo $item->subscriptionId; // 6
    echo $item->city;           // Blantyre
    echo $item->area;           // City Centre
}
```